# 2 devices with different amp requirements on same power supply

Tags: power-supply, power

I've got a 5V 40A DC power supply.  I want to connect one device which requires 5V 1A DC, and another device which requires 5V 30A DC.

Is it safe to wire these to the same supply on the same screw?  I'm worried about what will happen when the high amperage device draws a lot of power.  Will it flood my low amperage device with too much power?

Excuse my ignorance, don't know much about electricity.

Comment: Are these devices computers and/or is this a PC power supply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no problem: the 5-volt devices in parallel only draw 31 amps, so the power upply should be sufficient. Both devices will receive 5 volts, so there is no such thing as "flooding".

That said, if one device produces a lot of noise on the DC line, it could cause issues, but that is most unlikely with modern, certified, devices.